# How do I set up conditional content in excel based on multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

I'm working on a database for magic items for my d&d campaign, compiling several books and homebrew stuff into 1 file.
I have a list of prices based on the rarity of the item and whether or not it is consumable.
so the formula would looks something like this:

```
IF (C4 = 'Very Rare') AND (D4 = 'no') F4 = 30.000
```

I feel like this should be possible, but there are 5 levels of rarity, so I would need 10 IF statements for this formula. Can I do this in excel?

**edit: this is the table of prices I want to recreate with this formula.**
[image: pricelist]

**edit2: this is the file I'm trying to get the formula to work in.**
[image: item list file]

Comment: Do you want to check for a match for any of the possible values, and get the same result as long as it is any one of them, or are you really wanting to have a different result depending on which level of rarity is found, a bit like a lookup table?
Also, what result do you want if D4 is not "No"? Blank? Zero? Best to define it or you will just get "FALSE"

Comment: I want a different result based on the rarity; items that are more rare are more expensive. So like a lookup table.
Consumable items are half the price of a non-consumable item of equivalent rarity. So a Very Rare item where D4 is 'yes' would cost 15.000
if the D column gives neither a yes nor a no, it probably should just give a FALSE

Comment: Based on your image, which cells are C4, D4 and F4?

Comment: those cells are in another worksheet. I am trying to make a formula that enters the value from this table based on the rarity and consumability. I'm not trying to reference these cells themselves, if that makes any sense. 
what I'm trying to write in non-excel language is something like this:
IF rarity = common AND consumability = 'yes', price = 30
IF rarity = common AND consumability = 'no', price = 60
IF rarity = uncommon AND consumability = 'yes', price = 100
IF rarity = uncommon AND concsumability = 'no', price = 200

etc. for the other rarities. Does that make sense?

Comment: I suggest two (2) lookup Tables.  One for Consumable and one for not consumable. Then your formula first decides which table to use, based on consumability, and then does a lookup for rarity in the appropriate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rearrange your prices table into three columns, this becomes easy. Column headings would be something like this:

How rare  |  Price if consumable  |  Price if not consumable

I'll assume these are on a sheet called "Lookups", in cells A1:C6 (you said there were 5 options). You can use a simple VLOOKUP to find the correct row in that table and return a value from the correct column, such as this:

```
=VLOOKUP($C2,Lookups!$A$1:$C$6,2+($D2="No"),FALSE)
```

So that finds whatever is in C2 in the first column of the lookup table (note the $ for fixed references to that table so you don't run off the bottom of it when you copy your formula down), then gets a value from the second column, or the third if D2="No" (because that evaluates to TRUE, which is equivalent to a 1). The false just means you want an exact match for the description of rarity.

Once built, you can change you prices or add other levels of rarity ("Air", "Rocking horse eggs") as you see fit.

For bonus points, make your lookup table an actual table in Excel and name it "RarityPrices" (or whatever), in which case your formula would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP($C2,RarityPrices,2+($D2="No"),FALSE)
```

Slightly easier to read, and will expand if you add more rows to the table so you don't have to keep editing your formula.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like non-consumable items are double the price of, or at least, some multiplier of, consumable items. In which case, you can look up the "base" price of a rarity (the consumable price), then multiply that by the multiplier to get the non-consumable price.

You could optionally set the multiplier for each rarity as a different value (which later, you might want to tie to some other attribute). Anyway, suppose you have prices and multipliers:

[image]

Then you could use LET and XLOOKUP:

[image]

That formula:

```
=LET(x,XLOOKUP($H2,$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$C$6,"Unknown rarity"),INDEX(x,1,1)*IF(I2="No",INDEX(x,1,2),1))
```

We are using `XLOOKUP` to return both the base price and the non-consumable multiplier for the rarity in question into a variable called x. We can then refer to x in the second half of the formula and say

> multiply the first value from the array (i.e. the base price) by the second value from the array (i.e. the multiplier)
> if the Consumable column says no, or by 1 otherwise

Granted, `LET` and `XLOOKUP` are only available on more recent versions of Excel, so perhaps this answer can be considered mainly for information and as an example of the use of `LET` and a possible way to allow a little more flexibility in your data model later on.